# Image from app to mail

Tags: objective-c, macos, email

How can I do something like "share to mail"? Like in `NSSharingServices` when selecting mail. For example I have `NSImage` and I want to achieve result like in ***image2***. How can I do it? Any pointers?

***Image1:***
[image]

***Image2:***
[image]

To create message from text only I can do:

```
NSURL *     url;
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:"
       "?subject="
       "&body=text"
       ];
(void) [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
```

but I don't know what to do to create message with image.

---

I found a way to add attachment when using ScriptingBridge framework. Code:

```
MailApplication *mail = [SBApplication
                         applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Mail"];

MailOutgoingMessage *emailMessage =
[[[mail classForScriptingClass:@"outgoing message"] alloc]
 initWithProperties:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  @"this is my subject", @"subject",
  @"this is my content", @"content",
  nil]];

[[mail outgoingMessages] addObject: emailMessage];

emailMessage.visible = YES;


NSString *attachmentFilePath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"<my provided file path>"];
if ( [attachmentFilePath length] > 0 ) {

    MailAttachment *theAttachment = [[[mail
                                       classForScriptingClass:@"attachment"] alloc]
                                     initWithProperties:
                                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      attachmentFilePath, @"fileName",
                                      nil]];

    [[emailMessage.content attachments] addObject: theAttachment];
}
[emailMessage visible];
```

It works. But how to add NSImage to attachment? Maby I have to write NSImage to temporary file, then add as attachment and delete temporary file? Or what? Or maby I should somehow add NSImage to body?

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```
NSString *text = @"sometext";
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/logo57.png"]];
NSArray * shareItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:text, image, nil];

NSSharingService *service = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail];
service.delegate = self;
[service performWithItems:shareItems];
```

also make sure you put the NSSharingServiceDelegate in your headerfile of the delegate.